# Convert a sorted doubly linked list to a balanced binary search tree? How this recursion works?

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

This is not a duplicate question.

When we are converting the sorted array to BST, we do get left and right from `n/2` element from the left part and the right part. Whereas when we are trying to convert the double Linked list why we are getting right from `(len - (len / 2) - 1)`.

Basically, I wanted to understand why there is a difference and how to explain it to someone.

There are two pieces of code:

https://www.techiedelight.com/construct-height-balanced-bst-from-sorted-doubly-linked-list/

```
public static Node buildBalancedBST(List<Node> nodes, int start, int end)
    {
        // base case
        if (start > end) {
            return null;
        }
 
        // find the middle index
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
 
        // The root node will be node present at the mid index
        Node root = nodes.get(mid);
 
        // recursively construct left and right subtree
        root.prev = buildBalancedBST(nodes, start, mid - 1);
        root.next = buildBalancedBST(nodes, mid + 1, end);
 
        // return root node
        return root;
    }
```

https://www.ideserve.co.in/learn/convert-a-sorted-doubly-linked-list-to-balanced-binary-search-tree-bst

```
private ListNode convertDllToBST(int len) {
        if (len == 0) {
            return null;
        }
 
        ListNode left = convertDllToBST(len / 2);
        ListNode root = head;
        root.prev = left;
        head = head.next;
        ListNode right = convertDllToBST(len - (len / 2) - 1);
        root.next = right;
        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The two formulas are doing different computation.

In the first piece of code, `start + end / 2` find the index of the middle element of the array (the part of the array that's being converted).

Whereas in the second piece of code, `len - (len / 2) - 1` find the length of the second half of the list.

Comment: In the second code when it called recursively ex: total length is 7:  left  n/2, and 
right= len - (len / 2) - 1. How this workes.

Comment: In the second code, for a lenght of 7: the left half have a length of `7 / 2` = `3` (the result is truncated as value are `int` and not `float`) ; and the right half have a length of `7 - (7 / 2) - 1` = `3` (with 7/2=3 as before). We then have two half of lengh 3, plus the root: 7 nodes in total.

Comment: user3093845, if you think my answer helped you, can you upvote or even accept my answer. That way you are letting other peoples know that I helped you.

Comment: @meBean thanks for the quick response. Sorry for the late response.

method 1
       Start. end  prev. next
it1.   0.      7.       3.